# Groovy - parse json: how to find certain "block" in json response with the goal of further parsing it

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

Pre-condition:
I'm testing REST in SoapUI tool.
I'm sending request, and in result
I have json response, which I want to parse with help of groovy code:

```
    {"List": [
      {
      "id": 1,
      "data1": "xxx",    
      "data2":       {
         "node1": "1",
         "node2": "4",
         "node3": 1,
      }
   },
      {
      "id": 2,
      "data1": "yyy",    
      "data2":       {
         "node1": "2",
         "node2": "6",
         "node3": 2,
      }
   },
      {
      "id": 3,
      "data1": "zzz",    
      "data2":       {
         "node1": "2",
         "node2": "6",
         "node3": 2,
      }
   }
]}
```

Goal: I want to find certain block (e.g. that with "id" = 2), and continue to parse this block with the goal of further assertions.

E.g., I want to verify, that directly in the "block" with "id"=2, those node1/node2/node 3 are {2, 6, 2} correspondingly.

So, how to do it with groovy(in soapUI script step) ?

Comment: JsonSlurper can parse jsonstring to maps/arrays. After that it's just an iteration/find of elements...

Comment: Hi! sure, slurper seems to be suitable, but I stucked with finding Instance with certain id. Yes, we can find that "id = 2", but how to save that part of map, and only it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def data = new JsonSlurper().parse ...

def e = data.List.find{it.id==1}
assert e.data1=="xxx"
```